# create a matrix of given dimensions from a vector without replacement

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I want to create a matrix from a vector, but the number of entries isn't divisable by the dimensions.  example below.

```
vector1 <- c('a','b','c','d','e','f','g')
result1 <- a b c
           d e f
           g
```

I want the result to be 3 columns wide and fill as many rows as necessary.  I want empty spaces or something easily distinguishable at the end not replaced values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pre-calculate `nrow` and `ncol` to create matrix.

```
vector1 <- c('a','b','c','d','e','f','g')
ncol <- 3
nrow <- ceiling(length(vector1)/ncol)
matrix(vector1[seq_len(nrow * ncol)], ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)

#    [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,] "a"  "b"  "c" 
#[2,] "d"  "e"  "f" 
#[3,] "g"  NA   NA
```

Comment: Thank you for fixing my example.  I forgot to make the entries characters.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `stri_list2matrix`

```
library(collapse)
library(stringi)
stri_list2matrix(rsplit(vector1, as.integer(gl(length(vector1), 3, 
         length(vector1)))), byrow = TRUE)
#    [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,] "a"  "b"  "c" 
#[2,] "d"  "e"  "f" 
#[3,] "g"  NA   NA
```

#### data

```
vector1 <- c('a','b','c','d','e','f','g')
```